# VS Code folder structure layout

Tags: visual-studio-code

Recently the layout of how folders inside of folders are being displayed on my editor in the left panel has changed and I was looking for a way to change it back.

Currently I see this sort of layout where menu-item is a folder inside of the components folder but is on one line like components/menu-item

[image]

I would prefer it being displayed like how the page folder is being displayed under the src folder. I have looked in VS code settings but so far but did not see any such option to change the layout. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're looking for `Explorer: Compact Folders`. Disable it.

```
"explorer.compactFolders": false
```